# Append text input to a div element

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form in which I get by `id` an `input` field when a `button` is clicked, then write its content in a `div`.

However, I would like to have the input values appended at each successive button click rather than replaced.

How would I do that?

Here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("usr").value;     
   document.getElementById("listaa").innerHTML = x;
}
```

---

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="unesi">
<!-- ... -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="myFunction()">click me!</button>
<!-- ... -->
<div class="col-sm-6" id="listaa"></div>
```

Comment: If you want to list them – "*I want to get them listed*" – why not use a list (`<ul>`, or `<lol>`, with child `<li>` elements)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to be listed one after the other change the function:

```
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("usr").value;     
   document.getElementById("listaa").innerHTML += x + "<br>";
}
```

notice the `+=` to append text rather than replace it.